Is there a recommended maximum depth for the content tree in Sitecore
I know that Sitecore recommends no more than 100 child items beneath any given node and I don't know of any technical limit to the depth of the content tree, but is there a recommended/suggested limit here?

There is a setting inside Sitecore that recommends to have max depth till 20.
<setting name="MaxTreeDepth" value="20"/>

You can check this setting under the sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page.
Hope this helps!!!

Wow, thank you, I can't believe I missed this setting in all the years using Sitecore!
